# Firebase, variable as key name

Tags: javascript, variables, firebase

what I basically want to do is this:

```
variable = 'whatever';
fb.set({ variable : "More Stuff" });
```

So this will result in an entry that looks like:

```
whatever: "More Stuff"
```

Currently it just ends up as

```
variable: "More Stuff"
```

Can this be done?

Comment: In case you are wanting the name of the entry to be variable, simply do *var newRef = new Firebase("https://your-fb-id.firebaseio.com/" + variable);*

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For the latest version of Firebase, use brackets around the variable name:

```
firebase.database().ref("pathName").set({[variable] : 'MoreStuff'});
```

Using the other method of setting the index of the variable to the value will create an additional layer in the database structure.

Comment: can I use the same for push method?

Comment: Is it ok to use this approach in a very abstract way? i.e where you could have 3 fields in a document, and instead of writing a set method for each field i.e setName, setAge, setDescription, Is it ok to use a method like setData(fieldKey, fieldValue) therefore this saves having to write the same function 3 times, but does it make it difficult for testability or scalability ?

Comment: I read everywhere in the docs. Where did you find this info?

Comment: Honestly, I just tried different ideas that made sense to me until it worked, because I couldn't find anything in the docs either.

Answer (score 17):

Yes. The code is not working as expected because you are using object literal notation, which is the reason the it keeps the variable name as key, because that is how the notation works.

Solution

```
foo = {}; 
foo[variable] = 'more stuff'; 
fb.set(foo);
```

Comment: Is x foo in this case?

Comment: @MattCoady yes it was, I changed it to foo ;)

Comment: This actually sets a key ```foo``` with a value of ```[variable]: 'more stuff'```.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that @randomnamehere 's command didn't quite deliver what I expected, since I wanted to use a accumulated number - or in your case, a named index - inside a reference while still keeping multiple indexes. So the proper command should have actually been

```
firebase.database().ref(`pathName/${variable}`).set('More Stuff');
```

His original answer would actually replace the entire reference with a single named index inside it. I know because I learned it the hard way :P

Answer (score -2):

You can create an Empty `object` and set your variable as it's property and assign a value to it. Please see below:

```
let object: any = {};
 object[variable] = value
```

Comment: while this might be the correct answer, this is too short for it to be a good answer. Please provide some more details and reference.