# How to access map type variable with a dash character in firestore db

Tags: node.js, database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection as shown below:

```
user (collection)
    userUID (Document)
        token = "123"
        planet (Map)
            pl34-7ft (Map)
                planetName = "axiom"
                planetID = "pl34-7ft"
                island = "amrs"
```

I am trying to run query to find all users that has planet "axiom" in their account.

When I run the following code:

```
var ref = await firestoreDb.collection('user').where("planet.pl34-7ft.planetName", "==", "axiom").get().then(snapshot => { ... }
```

I got the following error:

Field "planet.pl34-7ft.planetName" is not  a valid Firestore field path.

When I change "p134-7ft" to a name without dash character, i.e. "malibu", then I do not get the error.

I am guessing firestore requires a special way to handle "dash" character?

Does anyone know how can I access a field path with a dash character?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please, try using brackets []:
where([planet.pl34-7ft.planetName], "==", "axiom")

You can see this post too:
[Firebase, variable as key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707639/firebase-variable-as-key-name)

Luck!

Comment: Hi, how can I achieve the same result in TypeScript